# React native repository pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a view class which will get me list of hospitals -

View.js

```
import {getHospitalList} from '...'

fetchHospitals = async () => {

        let response = await getHospitalList();
}
```

I have a business logic class `getHospitalList()` which makes an API call and also reads from AsyncStorage.

So what I need is whenever my view asks for a list of hospitals with `getHospitalList()`, the `getHospitalList()` should first return the view, a list of hospitals from AsyncStorage and make an API call and then store it to AsyncStorage and return the view, the actual list of hospitals from API.

How could I do that?

Comment: View? Do you mean view model or are you returning a JSX Element? Are you wondering how to return data from AsyncStorage and then async from the API call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--but `getHospitalList` should do just that, get the list of hospitals, which can be used in, say, a `<Hospitals />` component. Whatever's retrieving the hospitals should be responsible for just that. A JSX component should use that call to get the hospitals and display them, and that component can in turn be used in other components to display the list of hospitals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use context to achieve a repository pattern here how i implement it in typescript

App.tsx

```
const _HospitalService = new HospitalService()
const App = () => {
  return (
      <ServiceProvider service={{
        "HospitalService": _HospitalService
      }}>
         <AppContainer />
      </ServiceProvider>
   
  );
};
```

ServiceContext.tsx

```
interface ServiceType{
    [key:string]:IRepository
}
interface IServiceContext{
    service: ServiceType
}


const defaultDatabaseContext:IServiceContext={
    "service":{}
}


export const ServiceContext = createContext(defaultServiceContext)

const ServiceProvider = ({children,service}:{children:JSX.Element,service:ServiceType})=>{

    return (
        <ServiceContext.Provider value={{service}}>
            {children}
        </ServiceContext.Provider>
    )  
}

export default ServiceProvider
```

HospitalRepository.ts

```
class HospitalRepository {
   getHospitalList(){
       // your business logic
   }
}
```

View.tsx

```
const View = ()=>{
   const {service} = useContext(ServiceContext)
   fetchHospitals = async () => {
        const hospitalService = service['HospitalService']
        let response = await hospitalService.getHospitalList();
    }

   //view ui here
}
```

Reference: https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2021-03-19-react-context-for-dependency-injection-not-state/